# Mvc 4 Webgrid conditional htmlActionLinks

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, webgrid

I've got a webgridextensions class the defines "WebGridColumn" returns for different scenarios..

```
 public static WebGridColumn ApptLinksWSchedule(this WebGrid grid, HtmlHelper html)
    {

        return grid.Column(
            header: "",
            style: "actionColumn",
            format: item => new HtmlString(
                html.ActionLink("Schedule", "Schedule", new { ID = item.CourseExamApptID }, new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you'd like to schedule this Appointment?');" }).ToString()

            )
        );
    }


    public static WebGridColumn ApptLinksWCancel(this WebGrid grid, HtmlHelper html)
    {

        return grid.Column(
            header: "",
            style: "actionColumn",
            format: item => new HtmlString(
                html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { ID = item.CourseExamApptID }).ToString() + " | " +
                html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { ID = item.CourseExamApptID }).ToString() + " | " +
                html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Cancel", new { ID = item.CourseExamApptID }, new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you'd like to cancel this Appointment?');" }).ToString()
            )
        );
    }
```

In my view I need to conditionally apply an htmlActionLinks according to the value of a model property. If my model.AppointmentStatus  = "Scheduled", show one set of action links, if not show another set...

```
<div class="webgrid-wrapper">
<div id="grid">
    @grid.GetHtml(
        tableStyle: "webgrid",
        headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
        footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",
        alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
        selectedRowStyle: "webgrid-selected-row",
        rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style",
        columns: grid.Columns(grid.Column("StudentID", "SMUId"),
                                grid.Column("StudentName", "Name"),
                                grid.Column("CourseName", "Course"),
                                grid.Column("InstructorName", "Professor"),
                                grid.Column("ExamLength", "ExamLength"),
                                grid.Column("SchedExamBeginTime", "Time In"),
                                grid.Column("SchedExamEndTime", "Time Out"),
                                grid.Column("Notes", "Notes"),
                                grid.Column("AppointmentStatus", "Status"),

                                //THIS IS WHat I'd like to display in a column...

                                        //if (model.AppointmentStatus == "Scheduled")
                                        //{
                                        //    html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { ID = item.CourseExamApptID }).ToString() + " | " +
                                        //    html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { ID = item.CourseExamApptID }).ToString() + " | " +
                                        //    html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Cancel", new { ID = item.CourseExamApptID }, new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you'd like to cancel this Appointment?');" }).ToString()
                                        //}

                                        //html.ActionLink("Schedule", "Schedule", new { ID = item.CourseExamApptID }, new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you'd like to schedule this Appointment?');" }).ToString()





                                //THIS IS MY ORIGINAL CODE THAT WORKS with only needing same column and link for every record...

                                //grid.ApptLinksWCancel(Html)


            )
         )
</div>
```

How do I accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry everyone, I;m effing asleep over here, what i need is in the edits..Different links according to status value...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use a [ternary expression ?:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) for this, as in:

```
columns: grid.Columns(
    model.AppointmentStatus == "Scheduled" ? 
        grid.ApptLinksWCancel(Html) : grid.ApptLinksWSchedule(Html)
),
```

**Edit**

For something more complicated, you could add an extension method taking an extra parameter:

```
public static WebGridColumn ApptLinks(this WebGrid grid, HtmlHelper html, string status)
{
    if (status == "Schedule")
        return grid.ApptLinksWSchedule(html);
    else
        return grid.ApptLinksWCancel(html);
}
```

Use it in the same way:

```
columns: grid.Columns(
    grid.ApptLinks(Html, model.AppointmentStatus),
    ...
),
```

Comment: thanks man, this is useful! I edited my post because what I really need to see is each row having their own set of actionlinks, all determined by value of appointmentstatus..